# Skype Web SDK - when are profile fields populated?

Tags: skypedeveloper

We're using the Skype Web SDK to build chat capabilities into our web app.  We'd like to be able to show profile information for users in Skype in a business card-like format. This would have typical profile fields on it like title, department, company, location, etc.

All of these fields are listed in the SDK as properties of the Person object. However, it seems that only some of them are actually populated based on the information in my Active Directory user accounts. I am getting phone numbers, name, email address and avatarUrl, but that's about it.  Location, title, department, etc. are all empty strings.

Is there some security/privacy setting that is preventing this information from being displayed?  Or is there something special I need to do after doing a Person search to get those properties on the resulting Person objects?

Thanks!

Ben Gilbert

Answer (score 0):

The `Person` objects usually come from search results and from the contact list - in both cases UCWA returns partial data, e.g. display name, but not office location. Have you tried to invoke `person.department.get()` - this sends a GET request to UCWA to pull the missing property value?

Comment: Thanks!  Calling the get() methods solves my problem, I didn't realize it was only returning partial data by default.